# Graphics2D into BufferedImage

Tags: java, image, swing

I have found many ways to turn a image into a Graphics2d, but I am not sure how to turn my Graphics2d into a BufferedImage. How would I do this.

For example:

```
Graphics2D SomeGraphics;
SomeGraphics.drawImage(image, x,y,size,size);
SomeGraphics.fillRect(x,y,size,size);
```

Now how would I convert that Graphics into a Buffered Image?

Comment: In short you can't. Graphics is just a way to draw to somewhere, such as to a `BufferedImage`. You can't turn a brush into a paper.

Comment: Variable name should NOT start with an upper case character! Follow the Java standards and don't make up your own conventions.

Comment: Create a new instance `BufferedImage` and use `BufferedImage#createGraphics` to obtain a reference to it's `Graphics2D` context, paint, make sure you call `Graphics2D#dispose` when your done, otherwise it will continue to use up resources...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now how would I convert that Graphics into a Buffered Image?

Essentially, you can't.  You need to start with a `BufferedImage` and paint to it's `Graphics2D` context, for example...

```
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
g2d.fillRect(25, 25, 50, 50);
g2d.dispose();
```

The great thing is, the AWT and Swing API's work around the use of `Graphics` (which `Graphics2D` extends from), making it really easy to paint components to a `BufferedImage`

Comment: so with this, i can take a Buffered image and paint to it, like fillRect? If so thats not exactly what I wanted, but It will work great for what I want. If you cant convert directly, this is the second best thing. Thanks

Comment: `Graphics` is an abstract concept, you can't create `Graphics` object from nothing, it has to be associated with something (like an image or screen device or printer device), so yeah, this is the only way to get `Graphics` painted onto a `BufferedImage`